# Permutations and framed braids as cyclic operads

Tags: operads

The symmetric groups and the framed braid groups form an operad (in sets, not groups). It is straightforward to see this structure using the string diagrams.

It is also known that these operads are cyclic operads. However I am confused about how to see this extra structure using the string diagrams.

Does anyone have a nice description of this extra structure?

Comment: Avoid sticking to narrow tags. It is recommend to have at least one top-level tag in each post. Narrow is not a judgement on the topic, but just measured by the number of watchers and the number of questions.

Comment: @YCor It seems reasonable to have a top-level tag. I just can't find one that is appropriate. Looking at questions with the operads tag it appears that many of them are missing a top-level tag.

Comment: I think that ra.rings-and-algebras has to be interpreted in its broader sense, which encompasses operads.

Comment: That is a very broad interpretation. There is no linear structure in my question; only sequences of sets and then functions describing the structure.

Comment: Well, ra.rings-and-algebras is supposed to encompass universal algebra (see the tag info), where there's nothing linear.

Comment: The tag info does mention universal algebra, lattices and semigroups. I find that confusing. I would prefer to have a new top-level tag for abstract algebra or universal algebra (I am not clear what is intended to mean).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85258/discussion-between-bruce-westbury-and-ycor).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way of visualizing this using diagrams. Looking at diagrams means you look at the framed configuration space of points in a disc, i.e. at the configuration space of the unit bundle of the disc. Roughly speaking, the cyclic structure comes from swapping the "outer disc" with one of the point and it's unclear to me how to visualize that in that picture.

But this configuration space for $n$ points is equivalent to the moduli space of genus 0 topological surfaces with n+1 labeled, parametrized boundaries, or equivalently to the moduli space of genus 0 Riemann surfaces with $n+1$ labeled marked points and a tangent vector at each marked point. In this picture the cyclic structure is clear since the $n$th space of your operad involve $n+1$ points you get an obvious $S_{n+1}$-action.

Comment: This explains why the framed braid operad is in fact cyclic. I am trying to understand this in terms of the diagrams. This should not be hard but I am feeling confused.

Comment: Indeed, I'm sure you knew that already. I wasn't trying to answer your question, but rather arguing I don't think there's one because the "outer" boundary just don't shows on diagrams. That being said, you can see the cyclic structure if you allow yourself to work with the "cyclic PROP" of tangles rather than the operad of braids.

Answer (score 0):

The cyclic operad structure on the associative operad is described in the original paper of [Getzler and Kapranov](https://bpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/sites.northwestern.edu/dist/c/2278/files/2019/08/cyclic.pdf) at the top of page 7. I found this action very confusing until I imagined permutations as labels of rooted trees, and applied the $n+1$-cycle by the transformation in the attached picture.[image]